# Sinch API, Instant Messaging JS. Get all messages by senderID

Tags: javascript, sinch

I'm trying to get all messages by senderID.

```
onIncomingMessage: function(message) {
    // getAllMessagesBySenderId(); ?

    $('div#chatArea').prepend('<div class="msgRow" id="'+message.messageId+'"></div><div class="clearfix"></div>');

    $('div.msgRow#'+message.messageId)
        .attr('class', global_username == message.senderId ? 'me' : 'other')
        .append([
            '<div id="from">'+message.senderId+' <span>'+message.timestamp.toLocaleTimeString()+(global_username == message.senderId ? ',' : '')+'</span></div>', 
            '<div id="pointer"></div>',
            '<div id="textBody">'+message.textBody+'</div>',
            '<div class="recipients"></div>'
        ]);
    showUI();
}
```

Any ideas? 
Is it possible to get history of messages?
I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would save that in your own data structure, Sinch IM does not provide the "inbox" we deliver the message once to every device. Sorry